# Install tensorflow python API on Android gnuroot

Tags: android, python, tensorflow

I've installed Debian+python on an android table with GNURoot. Now I'm trying to install tensorflow python API, so that I can "import tensorflow" in my python code. My tablet CPU is arm 32 bits, so I can not install with pip because tensorflow only supports 64 bits.

I thus try to compile tensorflow from source. Tensorflow build system is Bazel, and I've not found any Bazel executable for linux arm 32 bits.

So I try to compile Bazel from source. But "./compile.sh" fails with error
"Protobuf compiler not found in third_party/protobuf/protoc-linux-arm32.exe"
I'm a bit reluctant to try and compile protobuf from source, because I've read somewhere that protobuf master may not be work with bazel.

Is there an alternative way to install tensorflow on arm32 ?

Comment: I've actually given up trying to install tensorflow; but I've manager to sucessfully install theano + Keras; so it's not so bad to design models ! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately building TensorFlow Python requires Bazel (for just C++ inference you can use the instructions at tensorflow/contrib/makefile), and this is quite an involved and buggy process. The best place to start is this post on setting things up on the Jetson board:

http://cudamusing.blogspot.com/2015/11/building-tensorflow-for-jetson-tk1.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to play with Keras it is possible on gnuroot. Instead of Tensorflow you can use Theano backend. I made it.

In this moment my Telefunken Outdoor WT4 phone [is running](https://blog.keras.io/how-convolutional-neural-networks-see-the-world.html) it.

It is very slow but it is working.

Comment: I agree, that's what I finally did as well: use theano :-)